# How do I get fraction of x?

Tags: programming

```
let fraction:CGFloat = 1.0 // This is fraction

let minValue:CGFloat = 60.0 // This is minimum value where slider starts
let maxValue:CGFloat = 240.0 // This is maximum value where slider end

let formula = (((maxValue)-(minValue)) * fraction) + minValue  //min value is 60 here 

 // Above formula translate to = (((240.0)-(60.0)) * 1.0) + 60 
 //to get an answer between 60 to 240 I'm adding "+60"     to the calculated answer and subtracting minValue from max value
//EVERYTHING IS PERFECT TILL HERE
```

**Now I'm confused on how do get reverse the fraction if the value is 74.0**

```
let initialSliderValue:CGFloat = 74.0 
let fractionOf74 = (initialSliderValue/maxValue) // 74.0/240.0 = 0.3083333333

let ans = (maxValue * fractionOf74) + 60 
// How do i get extact fraction to get answer of 74
//PLEASE NOTE I NEED TO ADD +60 to my answer so i get answer between 60 to 250
```

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about coding and belongs on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what language this is, but I believe you can fix this using

```
let fractionOf74 = (initialSliderValue-minValue)/(maxValue-minValue) // (74.0-60)/(240.0-60) = 0.0777777
```

Then

```
let ans = (maxValue - minValue) * fractionOf75 + minvalue //74.0
```

The key is that you just consider the fraction of the interval `[minValue, maxValue]`, but what you did was considering the fraction of the interval `[0, maxValue]`.

Comment: Wow it's perfect, Thanks now I get where i was going wrong, Thanks again Legend :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple math problem

lets call the fraction you want to be as x (fraction) which ranges from 0 to 1.0

we have the below formulae

let `formula` = (((maxValue)-(minValue)) * fraction) + minValue  //min value is 60 here

When x = 0 
`formula` will result in 60 which is your initial value

when x=1.0 the same `formula` will result in 240

so, we have

```
60 = ((240 - 60)*0)+60
```

and

```
 240 = ((240 - 60)*1.0)+60
```

now, we want to know for 74 whats the value of x, our formulae will be

```
74 = ((240-60)*x)+60
```

solving the above equation we get

```
(74 -60) = 180*x

14/180=x

0.07777777777 = x
```

thanks, Hope this helps!